# JPA : What is the behaviour of merge with lazy initialized collection?

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0

Here are the sequences leading to the question :

1. I have a Team record, and 3 Player records in the database. Team entity has a List that is using FetchType.LAZY, CascadeType.ALL
2. The search button on the webui is clicked
3. Query in the server side using JPA query is invoked, finding all the Team records, in this case, only 1 record of the team entity returned from the query (which has a proxy of the list of player entities)
4. Map this teamEntity to a DTO, and return this DTO to the webui, skipping the mapping of the list of player entities
5. Webui renders the DTO in a html form, ready to receive modifications from the user
6. User modifies the team's properties, like the date of when it's founded
7. The save button on the webui is clicked
8. Converting the DTO to the team entity, to be used to update the already existing team record
9. But in this case, if i were to use the em.merge(teamEntity), the team record will be updated, but what will happen to the list of players ? Because when converting from DTO to the team entity, the teamEntity has an empty list of players entities. And after merging, i notice that the teamEntity has 0 size of the details. But after refreshing that entity, em.refresh(teamEntity), it will return 3 of the detail size.

Im confused on :

1. Why is it the size is 0 after merged ? It's like not representing the record anymore
2. Before doing the test, i was thinking that the details will be removed since im merging a teamEntity with an empty detail.

Please enlighten me :)

Thank you !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

JPA Specification says:

> The semantics of the **merge** operation
>   applied to an entity X are as follows:
>
> - **If X is a detached entity, the state
>     of X is copied onto a pre-existing
>     managed entity instance X' of the same
>     identity or a new managed copy X' of X
>     is created.**
> - If X is a new entity
>     instance, a new managed entity
>     instance X' is created and the state
>     of X is copied into the new managed
>     entity instance X'.
> - If X is a
>     removed entity instance, an
>     `IllegalArgumentException` will be
>     thrown by the merge operation (or the
>     transaction commit will fail).
> - If X
>     is a managed entity, it is ignored by
>     the merge operation, however, the
>     merge operation is cascaded to
>     entities referenced by relationships
>     from X if these relationships have
>     been annotated with the cascade
>     element value `cascade=MERGE` or
>     `cascade=ALL` annotation.
> - For all
>     entities Y referenced by relationships
>     from X having the cascade element
>     value `cascade=MERGE` or `cascade=ALL`, Y
>     is merged recursively as Y'. For all
>     such Y referenced by X, X' is set to
>     reference Y'. (Note that if X is
>     managed then X is the same object as
>     X'.)
> - If X is an entity merged to X',
>     with a reference to another entity Y,
>     where `cascade=MERGE` or `cascade=ALL` is
>     not specified, then navigation of the
>     same association from X' yields a
>     reference to a managed object Y' with
>     the same persistent identity as Y.

As you can see, there is no magic here. The state of detached instance is copied into the newly created managed instance. Since your detached instance has an empty list, managed instance would have it too.

Further behaviour depends on ownership of relationship, since representation in the database reflects the owning side of relationship:

- If `Team` is the owning side, relationships between `Team` and `Player`s will be destroyed during flush (but `Player` itself would survive unless you have `orphanRemoval = true` on your relationship).
- Otherwise having the empty list in `Team` doesn't affect the database.

If you refresh the `Team` before flushing the context, all properties of `Team` are rewritten by values from the database, therefore list of `Player`s is restored (since the empty list of players wasn't flushed yet).

If you call `flush()` before calling `refresh()`, and `Team` is the owning side, list will be empty, since destruction of relationships was propagated to the database during `flush()`.

Comment: axtavt : Thank you for the explanation ! Just tested all the possibilities you mentioned, and now is beginning to understand the situation. About your statement : "If you call flush() before calling refresh(), and Team is the owning side, list will be empty, since destruction of relationships was propagated to the database during flush()", it will be like that if orphanRemoval true is used. If not, the children survive, and refresh will restore them in the entity's player list. Thanks again !

Comment: What JPA provider do you use? I'm familiar with Hibernate, without JPA, which also has merge operation and lazy collections, and when I try to read uninitialized collection from detached instance, I get an exception, not an empty collection. I think it is a bug of the provider. As a solution, initialize that collection before teamPlayer becomes detached.